# Set Windows Command Prompt with Unlimited Buffer Size

Tags: windows, command-line, scrolling

I am not sure whether `Screen Buffer` is the parameter which controls how much u scroll through the history in Windows Command Prompt.

I want to set `Unlimited Buffer` so that I can go past to at-least 1 day back what I have done in the command prompt. It's pretty annoying when I work so much on Command Prompt. It should set for any new command prompt which I launch and without executing any batch script/command.

Comment: Screen buffer is what you want, but it can only go to 9999.

Comment: And you need to make sure you specify the buffer size in "Defaults" not "Properties" so it applies to all new `cmd` windows: Right click cmd window titlebar > Select "Defaults"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Windows 10 console screen buffer beyond 9999?](https://superuser.com/questions/1331264/how-to-change-windows-10-console-screen-buffer-beyond-9999)