# How to change Windows 10 console screen buffer beyond 9999?

Tags: windows-10, console

The hard limit for the legacy Windows console was 9999.  I'm surprised to see that, in the new console's dialog box, MS have still set a limit of 4 figures (therefore 9999) for the maximum screen buffer size.  Is this a technical limitation or just the UI refusing to let you go beyond this?  If it's not a technical limitation, how can I increase it beyond 9999?

Comment: If you're getting more than 9999 lines why not just log/redirect to a file?

Comment: Try to use a better alternative for standard cmd: http://cmder.net/

Comment: When you say "new console", new since when? Will the box accept 5 digits, which are scrolled to the left on the 5th digit? Try "12345" to check.

Comment: @AFH Windows 10 has a new updated console that you can enable that makes improvements to certain things that I can't remember off the top of my head. Looks like buffer management wasn't one of them.

Comment: @MoonRunestar What console?  Do you mean command prompt?  Are we talking a command prompt or PowerShell?  Windows 10 defaults to PowerShell.

Comment: @Ramhound, ah, sorry. This is literally the console window that Command Prompt and PowerShell appear in by default. If you right click the console title bar, you can access the Default settings and Properties settings, which is where the new console can be enabled if I remember correctly.

Comment: So that's command prompt. Not Powershell.

Comment: So are you asking if Microsoft increased the buffer limit?

Comment: I have tested on W10/1709 and found that 9999 is indeed the limit: neither typing extra digits nor using the increment button helps. Neither could I find the set value in the registry, so it doesn't look as though a registry patch will provide an answer.

Comment: I have just checked on WinXP: although the input box appears to have space for 5 digits, only 4 can be entered and the behaviour is exactly as on Win10. Why would you want such a huge buffer?

Comment: WSL appears to have the puny limit of only 999, 1/10 that amount.  And re: @Seth, sometimes you don't know that you're going to *need* to scroll that far back.  I had a command with a lot of output that unexpected disappeared some files, but I can't scroll back to figure out if there was an error or what happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technical limitation of backscroll buffer in Windows (not only Win10) is not a 9999 but 32766.

You can't change it via console window properties but you may write small program which calls `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` and set it to desired value.

Or just use alternative terminals like [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the 32766 limit?

Comment: Definitely not. It's an experimental value and it comes from `SHORT` used in WinAPI

Comment: why 32766 and not 32767?

Comment: @phuclv I set it to 32767 in the registry and that doesn't seem to have any issues (Win11 22H2).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(228,32000)
```

where the first is the horizontal and second is vertical.

Haven't checked if it changes default, but at least it changes current window.

Comment: this does not persist.
however, I notice the default value in a new powershell window for me is `120,20000`.