# Windows command line window scroll limit

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, console, buffer, conhost

How to set Windows 10 command line window to unlimited scroll by default, like in Ubuntu?

I've set the only two possible option in the property dialog that may be related to buffer to 999, but still get overflowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum limit in Windows conhost.exe is 9999 lines. You can't set it to unlimited

- [Set Windows Command Prompt with Unlimited Buffer Size](https://superuser.com/q/995737/241386)
- [More lines in command window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1740876/995714)

Even Windows Terminal doesn't support infinite scrollback. There's an [issue created for that](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1410) on Github

Comment: uh.. how do you even get to 9999?  I can't set it above 999.

Comment: @Michael then it's probably a font size problem. You change it somehow that the font is so big and the last 9 disappears. It has always been 9999